# using jq to output in tsv unique values of an element with frequency of occurrence

Tags: csv, jq, frequency-distribution

given the following json, how could i create a tsv, that would output the frequencies of the values found in it (in the new element)?

```
{"_id":{"$someid":"545"},"new":"813 ROT","old":{"$someid":"5fe"}}
{"_id":{"$someid":"659889a"},"new":"9878 SU","old":{"$someid":"5bc"}}
{"_id":{"$someid":"986978754b"},"new":"813 ROT","old":{"$someid":"5bc1af"}}
```

desired output:

```
813 ROT 2
9878 SU 1
```

i can extract the values with .new, but do not know how to group them and create the tsv then

what i have tried:

```
def counter(stream):   reduce stream as $s ({}; .[$s|tostring] += 1);  counter(inputs | .new) | to_entries[] | {ItemId: (.key), Count: .value}
```

but gives output:

```
{
  "ItemId": "9878 SU",
  "Count": 1
}
{
  "ItemId": "813 ROT",
  "Count": 1
}
```

i use version of jq found in ubuntu 16.04 repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this jq filter:

```
jq -sr 'group_by(.new)|.[]|[.[0].new, length]|@tsv'
813 ROT 2
9878 SU 1
```

Option `-s` allows to get full content of the file into an array (to apply the filter to the full content).

Option `-r` displays raw data.

The `group_by` function groups into an array all object having the same `new` key.

The `.[0].new` gets the value of the key `new` and `length` the number of key with the same value.

The operator `@tsv` formats into tab separated values.